# react.js -jquery method does not work

Tags: jquery, node.js, reactjs, react-async

The app uses node.js and react.js (namely [react-async](https://github.com/andreypopp/react-async) ). So there is a react component that has a click handler inside which I want to get the class names(namely `minus_decrement` and `inline_block`) of that component. I used jQuery inside node.js (details [here](http://www.hacksparrow.com/jquery-with-node-js.html)) as well.

```
var MinusDecrement=React.createClass({

       clickHandler:function(e){

                    $div = $(this);

                    //$div=this.refs.minusDecElem.getDOMNode();

                    var className=$div.attr('class');
                   // var classNameReact=$div.attr('className');
                    if(window.console){

                     console.log("className = "+className);

                           } 

                   e.stopPropagation();

    },      

    render:function(){

        return (

             <span className="minus_decrement inline_block" onClick={this.clickHandler} >&nbsp;-&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>     

        );

    }

});
```

When I create the component with the  following line

`<MinusDecrement></MinusDecrement>`

, console output shows `undefined`. I tried with `.attr(className)` and `this.refs.minusDecElem.getDOMNode()` after adding `href` to the `span` element but in vain. Both alternate codelines are mentioned in comments.

How to get the class name though jQuery then?

Comment: Why do you need to do this? Generally React is better without direct DOM manipulation.

Answer (score 1):

By calling `$(this)` you are passing React Component object to jQuery. You should retrieve DOM Node first:

```
clickHandler: function (e) {
    $div = $(this.getDOMNode());
    var className = $div.attr('class');
    if (window.console) {
        console.log("className = "+className);
    } 
    e.stopPropagation();

}
```

Also you can use `this.refs` when you pass `ref` property to one of elements:

```
render: function () {
    return (
        <span ref="minusDecElem" className="minus_decrement inline_block" onClick={this.clickHandler} >&nbsp;-&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>     
    );
}
```

Comment: your edit removed the comments from OP. rolled it back however. What is the problem with the way I used `href` (see comments in code)? Do I just need to wrap it with `$` ?

Answer (score 0):

Got the solution myself. The following line

`var $div = $(this)`

should be replaced with

`var $div=$(e.target)`

Comment: why? Why are you doing this though? You shouldn't be using jQuery here

Comment: @zackify, without jQuery how could I get the class name ? Do you opt for vanilla JS?

Comment: set the classname to a state variable. Like `this.state.spanClass` then just modify that variable and the class will update. `this.state.spanClass` will always hold the current value.

Comment: It's pretty easy to get the class name without jQuery: `e.target.className`.